# Getting value for Excel file marker in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledb

I need to take some markers which are already set in an excel file. I am loading the file with OleDbDataAdapter and after that i fill a DataTable but i can't find a list of markers there. Can anyone tell me how can i get access to such a list or even if it is possible? Thanks.

by marker, i understand a name given to a pair of row/column and even an aria of rows/columns.

I have done it like this :

```
        string FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Release.xls";
        string currentSheet = "BOX";
        Application excelApp = new Application();
        Workbooks excelWorkbooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
        Workbook report = excelWorkbooks.Open(FileName, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, false, false, false);
        Worksheet ws = report.Sheets[currentSheet];
```

all the names are read with :

```
        public static List<Name> GetNamedRanges(Workbook activeWorkbook)
    {

        List<Name> namedRanges = new List<Name>();
        Name name;
        for (int i = 0; i < activeWorkbook.Names.Count; i++)
        {
            name = activeWorkbook.Names.Item(i + 1);

            namedRanges.Add(name);
        }
        return namedRanges;
    }
```

Pay attention that every time you run the program an excel process will be launched and it will not be closed at the end. That's why you have to use a trick :

```
            private static void CheckExcellProcesses(ref Hashtable myHashtable)
    {
        Process[] AllProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
        myHashtable = new Hashtable();
        int iCount = 0;

        foreach (Process ExcelProcess in AllProcesses)
        {
            myHashtable.Add(ExcelProcess.Id, iCount);
            iCount = iCount + 1;
        }
    }
```

Verify the processes when you start the application, and once again after the instantiation of the new excel process. At the end kill the the one existing in the second list and that doesn't exist in the first list.

Ok, that's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you access the Excel sheet via ADO.NET it's not possible to access the "markers". You have to think as your excel sheet as a table.